# SSO to third app from Salesforce using Azure AD

Tags: single-sign-on, activedirectory, azure-active-directory

We've implemented a SSO to Salesforce using Azure AD. This SSO works.

From internal Salesforce we want to do a SSO to a Document Management System. We've implemented the SSO using Azure AD to this third system. We can acces to the DMS directly, but in a embedded page from Salesforce a message of you can't access to microsoft.login.com appears.

Is there a solution?

This is the error (in our case the error is in the DMS page):
[image]

Comment: So Azure AD is the Identity Provider in both cases, just that you are trying to proxy through Salesforce to the DMS? I'm just trying to understand, Login Azure AD --> SSO Salesforce -- SSO DMS? If that is correct, where does the Salesforce page live (internal, community, ...)? when you say embedded what do you mean?

Comment: @Glen De Marcos. We have a embedded page (an iframe in a lightning component from our SFDC), we want SSO in SFDC (it works with azure), and when the user enters in the embedded page, an error appears (see the error in the imagen)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I understand the error "you can't access to microsoft.login.com" is logged in the browser's console. Are there any other errors in the console? It could be a CSP configuration issue.

Comment: Could be cross domain security controls in the browser